# Compare the numbers within different string using Python

Tags: python

I have two types of addresses:

```
Unit 5, 123 Fake Street Drive
123 Fake St Dr, Unit 5
```

How can I use Python to compare the two addresses by the numbers?

For example:

```
Unit 5, 123 Fake Street Drive -> [5,123]
123 Fake St Dr, Unit 5 -> [123,5]

TRUE

123 Fake Street Drive -> [123]
123 Fake St Dr, Unit 5 -> [123,5]

FALSE

Unit 5, 155 Fake Street Drive -> [155,5]
123 Fake St Dr, Unit 5 -> [123,5]

FALSE
```

All I have now is:

```
if bool(set([int(s) for s in address.split() if s.isdigit()]) & set([int(s) for s in address2.split() if s.isdigit()])):
```

I want to find out if one list of numbers is the same as another list of numbers regardless of the order.

Comment: just compare the sets with `==`, that should work.

Comment: Just to make sure, but the if the addresses are `Unit 1, 2 Street` and `2 A completely different street, unit 1` the output should be `False`?

Comment: Try `"1, 2".split()` you'll get `1,`: not all digits: fails.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to build `set`s of extracted numbers and compare them with `==`. `set` supports equality very well.

Another problem here is that `str.split()` won't work well for instance for `5,`. So `isdigit()` fails and your sets aren't equal.

Let me suggest `re.findall` to find digits, put them into sets and compare, using `\d+` or `\b\d+\b` to avoid digits inside words (like `N2P` for instance)

```
import re

address="Unit 5, 123 Fake Street Drive"
address2 = "123 Fake St Dr, Unit 5"

pattern = r"\b\d+\b"
print(set(re.findall(pattern,address))==set(re.findall(pattern,address2)))
```

This yields `True`, whereas if I change/add/remove one number from one of the lists above, I get `False`

As suggested in comments, that above fails if there are repeated numbers in one string, and not in the other: we could have a false positive since `set` clobbers duplicates.

If that's an issue, then replacing `set` with `collections.Counter` fixes that

```
collections.Counter(re.findall(pattern,address))==collections.Counter(re.findall(pattern,address2))
```

works too, `Counter` is a dictionary and compares to other dictionaries.

Comment: `{5} == {5,5} `; `return`s `True` (it should `return False` here), you'll need a `Counter` or multiset

Comment: you're right! OP example doesn't cover that. Good point. Edited with `Counter`, fits right in place.

Comment: One more question, can I distinguish numbers that are not inside a word? For example, I don't want to capture numbers in postal codes such as "N2P"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a sorted list, not a set. The set cannot distinguish between "Unit 1, 1 street X" and "1 Street Y" - but a sorted list will do.